# Erro na utilização dos filter_input no PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

Olá, pessoal. Tenho um  e estou tentando tratar os dados dele no arquivo php. (Estou utilizando AJAX para enviar para o arquivo PHP).

A consulta era realizada normalmente antes de eu colocar os filter_input. Porém, após colocá-los, a consulta não é mais realizada.

Vocês conseguem apontar um erro que eu esteja cometendo na utilização dos filtros.

**Imagem do form abaixo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código HTML**

```html
<form id="formulario-consulta">
  <!-- FORMULÁRIO DE PESQUISA -->

  <!--div superior com as datas-->

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 form-group">
    <h5>Filtrar por atividade :</h5>
    <div class="radio">
      <select name="prioridade" id="prioridade" class="input-sm form-control">
        <option value="Todos" selected>TODOS</option>
        <option value="Comum">COMUM</option>
        <option value="Extra">EXTRA</option>
        <option value="Urgente">URGENTE</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2 form-group">
    <h5>Filtrar por data de:</h5>
    <div class="radio">
      <select name="data" id="data" class="input-sm form-control">
        <option value="inicio">INÍCIO</option>
        <option value="finalizacao">FINALIZAÇÃO</option>
        <option value="vencimento" selected>VENCIMENTO</option>
      </select>
    </div>

  </div>




  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
    <h5 class="col-sm-3  col-xs-12">De:</h5>
    <input type="date" name="dataInicial" id="dataInicial" class="col-xs-12 input-sm form-control ">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2  form-group">
    <h5 class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Até:</h5>
    <input type="date" name="dataFinal" id="dataFinal" class="col-xs-12 input-sm form-control">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-lg-12 "></div>
  <!--divisor-->


  <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-1 ">
    <h5>Código</h5>
    <div class="radio">
      <select name="cod" id="cod" class="input-sm form-control">
        <option></option>
        <?php
          while($linha_cod = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_cod))
          {
         ?>
          <option id="<?php echo $linha_cod['EMPRESAS'];?>" value="<?php echo $linha_cod[" COD "];?>">
            <?php echo $linha_cod["COD"]; ?>
          </option>
          <?php
          }
         ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" col-sm-7 cols-sm-offset-0 col-lg-6">
    <div class="">
      <h5>Cliente</h5>
      <select name="empresas" id="empresas" class="input-sm form-control">
        <option></option>
        <?php
         while($linha_empresas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_empresas))
         {
         ?>
          <option id="<?php echo $linha_empresas['COD'];?>" value="<?php echo $linha_empresas[" EMPRESAS "];?>">
            <?php echo $linha_empresas["EMPRESAS"];?>
          </option>

          <?php
          }
         ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" col-sm-3 col-lg-2">

    <h5>Tributação</h5>
    <select name="tributacao" id="tributacao" class="input-sm form-control">
      <option></option>
      <?php
         while($linha_tributacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_tributacao))
         {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $linha_tributacao[" TRIBUTACAO "];?>">
          <?php echo $linha_tributacao["TRIBUTACAO"];?>
        </option>

        <?php
         }
        ?>
    </select>

  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-lg-12 "></div>
  <!--divisor-->

  <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-6 ">
    <div class="">
      <h5>Atividade</h5>
      <select name="atividade" id="atividade" class="input-sm form-control">
        <option></option>
        <?php
          while($linha_atividade = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_atividade))
          {
         ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $linha_atividade[" TIPO_ATIVIDADE "];?>">
            <?php echo $linha_atividade["TIPO_ATIVIDADE"]; ?>
          </option>

          <?php
          }
         ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 form-group">
    <h5>Status</h5>
    <select name="status" id="status" class="input-sm form-control">
      <option></option>
      <?php
          while($linha_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_status))
          {
         ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $linha_status[" STATUS "];?>">
          <?php echo $linha_status["STATUS"]; ?>
        </option>

        <?php
          }
         ?>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="botao-click-dashboard" id="botao-click-dashboard">
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-2 form-group">
    <h5>Pesquisar</h5>
    <input name="enviar" id="enviar" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary  btn-block  form-control" type="submit" value="Buscar">

  </div>

</form>
```

**Código dos filtros:**

```html
<?php


      
//PREENCHE AS VARIÁVEIS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DOS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO

filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$pegaropcao   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prioridade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$tipodedata = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'data', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//$dataInicial = !empty($_POST["dataInicial"]) ? $_POST["dataInicial"] : null;
$dataInicial = !empty($_POST["dataInicial"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null;
//$dataFinal  = !empty($_POST["dataFinal"]) ? $_POST["dataFinal"] : null;
$dataFinal = !empty($_POST["dataFinal"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataFinal', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : null;
$cod = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cod', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//$empresas   = !empty($_POST["empresas"]) ? $_POST["empresas"] : "";
$empresas   = !empty($_POST["empresas"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'empresas', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
//$tributacao = !empty($_POST["tributacao"]) ? $_POST["tributacao"] : "";
$tributacao = !empty($_POST["tributacao"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tributacao', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : "";
//$atividade  = !empty($_POST["atividade"]) ? $_POST["atividade"] : "";
$atividade = !empty($_POST["atividade"]) ? filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'atividade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : ""; 
    
$status = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'status', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
$condicao = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'botao-click-dashboard', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if(is_string($_SESSION["nome"])){
 $responsavel = $_SESSION["nome"];
}else{
 die("A SESSION[nome] não tem caracter String");
 exit;   
}
?>
```

Comment: qual erro está sendo exibido?

Comment: O tenso é que não está sendo exibido erro no PHP. Está sendo exibido erro no AJAX com os dados do retorno da consulta. Está dizendo que o AJAX não está recebendo dados de retorno.

Comment: e não aparece registro no db tbm?

Comment: Não. Agora como teste, eu tirei os filter_input e fiz diretamente com o $_POST e deu certo. O erro então está na utilização dos filtros. Creio eu que eu tenha feito algo de errado. Só não consigo descobrir o que.

Comment: Pq vc não pega as datas da seguinte forma, por ex.: `$dataInicial = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));` Utilizando o formato do seu sistema, poderia ser `'d-m-Y'`. Faça isso em todos do tipo data, para todos.

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro, mas por que eu faria isso ? Da forma que eu estava fazendo estava dando certo. Começou a dar errado somente quando coloquei os filtros. Adicionando valor na variável, diretamente do $_POST, estava dando certo.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Estava dando certo da forma anterior, agora, ao utilizar os filtros, trate as datas. Faça o teste! No caso que enviei acima, como vc trata ali nnum operador ternário, seria: `$dataInicial = !empty($_POST["dataInicial"]) ? DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) : null;`

Comment: A data pode ser tratada como STRING normalmente ?

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson sim! se liga onde usa ternário e onde não usa. E aplica de acordo. Também vale lembrar de como sua data é pega no POST (00-00-0000), ou (00/00/0000). E também, numa segunta parte, avalie o uso do `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` para o que não for string e sim integer

Comment: Fabiano, infelizmente deu erro. O AJAX não recebeu dados de retorno da consulta. Fiz exatamente da forma que você falou e adicionei as condições ternárias...

Comment: Mas olhando o meu código, existe algo de errado nele ?

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Tire o `filter_input` da condicao ternária: 
`$dataInicial = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dataInicial = (!empty($_POST["dataInicial"])) ? $dataInicial: null;`

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Qual o objetivo do `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` na primeira linha? Outra, coloque o html do formulário.

Comment: @FabianoMonteiro, fui recomendado a utilizar filtros em todos os campos. Inclusive aqueles que são populados dinamicamente. No campo data, eu coloquei pois achei que não haveria problema.

Comment: @ThiagoPetherson Eu digo o da primeira linha, que não tem nenhuma variável recebendo. O que ele faz ali? Comente aquela linha, pois ele não tem um objetivo ali. Fez o teste tirando o filter_input do ternário? Tire o filter_input da condicao ternária, faça assim: `$dataInicial = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); $dataInicial = (!empty($_POST["dataInicial"])) ? $dataInicial: null;` Quando digo tirar, é para fazer o tratamento antes de usar a condição ternária. Trate a variável antes com o filter_input e depois use-a no operador ternário.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92680/discussion-between-fabiano-monteiro-and-thiago-petherson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um `filter_input` solto, sem objetivo na primeira linha do seu código.

Qual o objetivo do: `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` Ele deve ser removido do código.

Depois, tire o `filter_input` que está dentro da condição ternária. Faça o tratamento antes, ficando assim:

```
 $dataInicial = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dataInicial', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

 $dataInicial = (!empty($_POST["dataInicial"])) ? $dataInicial : null;
```

Depois verifique também os campos que são numérico e estão sendo tratados como `string`, veja alguns filtros em: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Fora os filtros, vc pod eutilizar as flags de cada tipo de filtro:

O filtro FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING remove tags e remove ou codifica caracteres especiais de uma string.
Possíveis opções e flags:

> FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES - Não codifica aspas
>
> FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW - Remove caracteres com valor ASCII < 32
>
> FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH - Remove caracteres com valor ASCII > 127
>
> FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW - Codifica caracteres com valor ASCII < 32
>
> FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH - Codifica caracteres com valor ASCII > 127
>
> FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP - Encode o caractere "&" para `&amp;`

Ex:

```
filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```